# Select next row from a query ordered by a column value (in mysql) each time I submit the form

Tags: mysql, row

First of all, let me tell you that I am pretty novice at PHP & MySQL and trying to learn. So I created a webapp where a random apartment number is to be shown against a name of person ordered by membership number seniority. The apartment number and name of persons come from separate tables. 
I was able to get a random name by implementing the query like this-

```
SELECT bd, rank, name FROM person ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 1
```

But what I need is - when I submit the form it will show the most senior person's name and a random apartment number against him, when I click to submit the form again then the next senior person and a random apartment number and so on. In that case what my query should be?
My code looks like this-

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$query = "SELECT house_no FROM houses ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    global $won;
    $won = $row['house_no'];
    echo $won;
}

$query2 = "SELECT bd, rank, name FROM person ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $winner_rank = $row2['rank'];
    $winner = $row2['name'];
    $winner_bd = $row2['bd'];
    global $winner, $winner_bd, $winner_rank;

    echo $row2['rank']. " ";
    echo $row2['name']. ", ";
    echo "Member No/".$row2['bd'];
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help, but i don't think i fully understand what you are trying to accomplish with the code. Try commenting each step of the code and moreover i don't know what the structure of the database is like.

But from what i understand ==> when I submit the form it will show the most senior person's name and a random apartment number against him, when I click to submit the form again then the next senior person and a random apartment number and so on.

//to make sure an apartment is not issued to a member twice.
i suggest that you have a column called assigned in both users and apartment tables that will have a default value of 0

so, when you select any value for user and apartment, change the value of that column to 1.

//for the senior member
//I assume you have a users table :)
I think the most senior person will have the lowest id number in the db.

Select all the members that as a value of 0 in the assigned column then order by the id, limit result to 1

then save that value in a variable.

//for random apartment
//I assume you have a table for apartments
Just select the id and apartment number that has an assigned valued of 0 order by rand and limit to 1 then save it in a variable.

//echo the variables